# How to customize the switch button in a Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, customization, flutter-widget

In my application, I want the switch is used to toggle a setting between on/off which is true/false respectively. When I went to build it, it turned out that Flutter provides a default switch, but it is not what I want. I want to customize it accordingly to my UI.

This is the Flutter switch button:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

How can I make it possible for my UI?

Comment: Try this: https://medium.com/@felixblaschke/custom-animated-control-elements-with-flutter-8c0d352d7136

Comment: you can watch this tutorial here :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYNbMnaEnmA

Comment: just use CupertinoSwitch instead of Switch

Comment: No need to use any package for this. This is available on Flutter SDK when enabling Material 3 with `useMaterial3: true` from ThemeData

Answer (score 53):

Set

```
bool _switchValue = true;
```

in your *screen.dart* file:

```
 CupertinoSwitch(
              value: _switchValue,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _switchValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Please explain why and how your solution works. Maybe add a reference or link a documentation and please properly format your posts.
However, im not sure your answer solves OP question. He asked about the design, not value-switching.

Comment: they want design like switchbutton on ios and CupertinoSwitch  solve what they want and i set "bool _switchValue=true;"   to just know is the var the contain the state of switchbutton

Comment: How do you make the circluar button to be bigger thatn the strip?

Comment: use Switch widget, CupertinoSwitch is using the switch of ios devices , but if you wanna the normal switch use the switch of Matrial design

Answer (score 26):

**Create a custom switch class**

```
class CustomSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  CustomSwitch({Key? key, required this.value, required this.onChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CustomSwitchState createState() => _CustomSwitchState();
}

class _CustomSwitchState extends State<CustomSwitch>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation? _circleAnimation;
  AnimationController? _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 60));
    _circleAnimation = AlignmentTween(
            begin: widget.value ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: widget.value ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _animationController!, curve: Curves.linear));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController!,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if (_animationController!.isCompleted) {
              _animationController!.reverse();
            } else {
              _animationController!.forward();
            }
            widget.value == false
                ? widget.onChanged(true)
                : widget.onChanged(false);
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 45.0,
            height: 28.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
              color: _circleAnimation!.value == Alignment.centerLeft
                  ? Colors.grey
                  : Colors.blue,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0, right: 2.0, left: 2.0),
              child: Container(
                alignment:
                    widget.value ? ((Directionality.of(context) == TextDirection.rtl) ? Alignment.centerRight : Alignment.centerLeft ) : ((Directionality.of(context) == TextDirection.rtl) ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight),
                child: Container(
                  width: 20.0,
                  height: 20.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Call this class as widget and use the value parameter to set the state of the switch**

```
bool _enable = false;

CustomSwitch(
   value: _enable,
   onChanged: (bool val){
      setState(() {
         _enable = val;
      });
   },
),
```

Comment: It's not working proper.It's giving alway false value when change switch.First ,You should be test it .

Comment: It doesn't look like Animation animates something here. `_circleAnimation.value == Alignment.centerLeft ? AppColors.grey2 : AppColors.primary4` it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: It works but you have to edit the small circle Alignment to `alignment:_circleAnimation.value,`

Answer (score 24):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch or fork it and modify it to your needs.

#### Full code

```
import 'package:custom_switch/custom_switch.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange
      ),
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  bool status = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Switch Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomSwitch(
              activeColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
              value: status,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print("VALUE : $value");
                setState(() {
                  status = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            Text('Value : $status', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0
            ),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can i remove the On and Off tags?

Comment: @AndreiMarin comment "value:status".

Answer (score 11):

For a custom switch, I used this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_switch

You can customize the height and width of the switch, the border radius of the switch, the colors, the toggle size, etc.

Install:

```
dependencies:
     flutter_switch: ^0.0.2
```

Import:

```
import 'package:flutter_switch/flutter_switch.dart';
```

Sample Usage:

```
FlutterSwitch(
     height: 20.0,
     width: 40.0,
     padding: 4.0,
     toggleSize: 15.0,
     borderRadius: 10.0,
     activeColor: lets_cyan,
     value: isToggled,
     onToggle: (value) {
          setState(() {
                isToggled = value;
          });
     },
),
```

[image: Flutter Switch]

Comment: Hi, [Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Nick, it is good that you (and other) contributes some helpful stuffs, But you should carefully test it.Widget won't updates when I change the value by setState. Look at CupertinoSwitch for example. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve such a design using [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch_button):

This usage is from their README file:

```
import 'package:custom_switch_button/custom_switch_button.dart';

bool isChecked = false;

return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Custom Switch Button example app'),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              isChecked = !isChecked;
            });
          },
          child: Center(
            child: CustomSwitchButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              unCheckedColor: Colors.white,
              animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
              checkedColor: Colors.lightGreen,
              checked: isChecked,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Final result:

[image]